# Fitting Logisitic regression model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have fitted a logistic regression model in r using 'glm' function. It returns two warning messages that "algorithm did not converge " and "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred".
How can I resolve these problems?,
More specifically, the data are
      ym<-c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1, 0, 1, 1);
     xm <-c-1.2554919, -0.6029080, -0.8017795, -0.1389861,  1.4679619,   -0.8527954, 1.1096942 ,-1.0095326,  1.5500604 , 0.5622234);
     glm(ym~xm,family=binomial(link = "logit"))

Comment: Well, you can start by *providing your data and your code* so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/5055).